# Create an NSArray which contains only values of one parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, nsarray

I have an existing `NSArray` which contains object of certain type.
I need to go through it many times and output a string chaining one of the object component.

For example: I have a property in this object called: gameId- I need to loop over the array and output a string contains all the games ids in one string: `123,453,543`

I did like that:

```
- (NSString *) returnStringPresentationOfAParameter:(NSString *)paramName inArray:(NSArray *)array
 {
     NSMutableArray *arrayWithParam;
     for(MyObject *object in array)
     {
         if([paramName isEqualToString: @"gameId"])
         {
           [gamesArrayWithParam object.gameId];
         }
         else if([paramName isEqualToString: @"date"])
         {
           [gamesArrayWithParam object.date];
         }
     //etc...
     }
   return [arrayWithParam componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 }
```

Do someone have any idea how to make it more efficient?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using hashtables or direct lookup with NSDictionary and indexing based on keys? Another quick fix would be to replace the "MyObject *" with id in the for-loop to use fast enumeration.

Comment: I don't want to create 10 different dictionaries and it's also suppose to be dynamic. 
If I will replace the MyObject I won't be able to reach the necessary properties.

Comment: Yes, you will be able to access the properties. Just cast the object to (MyObject).

Comment: @AlexanderW using MyObject* in the loop declaration does not forgo fast enumeration. This is simply a cast just as you are suggesting to do inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
[[array valueForKey:paramName] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

To get your final string.

Edit: make sure the objects stored in the array are key-value compliant

Comment: NSArray is a class which is not key value coding-compliant

Comment: [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey:) says : Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

Comment: it throws an exception

Comment: I just tested, works fine for me. Are you sure the array you are receiving has been allocated as an NSArray ? Is MyObject key-value compliant?

Comment: For KVC the dictionary's keys must be NSStrings. Are they? What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
- (NSString *)gameIDListFromGameItems:(NSArray *)gameItems withComponentSeparator:(NSString *)separator {
    NSArray *gameIDs = [gameItems arrayByMappingWithBlock:^id(GameItem *gameItem) {
        return gameItem.gameID.stringValue;
    }];
    return [gameIDs componentsJoinedByString:separator];
}
```

---

```
@implementation NSArray (Additions)
- (NSArray *)arrayByMappingWithBlock:(MapBlock)block {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (id obj in self) {
        id mappedObj = block(obj);
        if (!mappedObj) {
            mappedObj = [NSNull null];
        }
        [array addObject:mappedObj];
    }
    return array;
}
@end
```

The advantage of this approach over key value coding is that the compiler can check that you are actually referencing real properties. If you changed the name of the gameID property, it would be caught at compile time.